# jQuery and OnClick

Tags: jquery, onclick, fadeout

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("body").css("display", "none");
$("body").fadeIn("slow");
    $("a.link").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("body").fadeOut("slow", redirectPage);        
    }); 
    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }
});
</script>
```

It does not work "fadeOut" when using "onclick". As can be implemented without using the "href"?

```
<a class="link" onclick="window.location='index.php'">index.php</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You script works with this:

```
<a class="link" href="http://google.de">index.php</a>
```

It fades out the "body" and afterwards it redirects to google.

It also works without the href:

```
<a class="link">index.php</a>
```

In this case it will just "refresh" the current page.

If you don't want to store the link within the href-attribute, you can do this:

```
<a class="link" data-link="index.php">index.php</a>
```

This is valid HTML and you can, instead of the href-attribute read the new one:

```
$(this).attr('data-link');
```

You don't have to set another "onclick" handler within the link. Because this one will fire first, before the jQuery event handler gets it's work done.

Answer (score 0):

why not?

```
<a class="link" href='index.php'>index.php</a>
```

you are using 2 click handlers for one event, and this results in unexpected behaviors.

Comment: Need to do without the "href"

Comment: I added a version without the href-attribute in my example.

Answer (score 0):

You are already defining an onclick handler in your  tag that immediately changes windows.location.

The other handler (defined via JQuery) is fired too, but has not the time to run because the first one changes the page.

You have to eliminate the ont in the  tag to see the fadeout.